# Duplicate class on jetified-guava-31.1-android.jar and jetified-listenablefuture-1.0.jar

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, dependency-resolver

I am Getting duplicate classes on Android Unity build.while the resolver run succesfully. Error detailed are as follow.

`UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <c3a2c42a45424b88b29dfadf7f497cbb>:0) UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <c3a2c42a45424b88b29dfadf7f497cbb>:0) UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <c3a2c42a45424b88b29dfadf7f497cbb>:0) UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools.RunJava (System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.Action`1[T] progress, System.String error) (at :0)
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, Unity.Android.Gradle.AndroidGradle androidGradle, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <c3a2c42a45424b88b29dfadf7f497cbb>:0) Rethrow as GradleInvokationException: Gradle build failed UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, Unity.Android.Gradle.AndroidGradle androidGradle, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at :0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildGradleProject.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at :0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at :0)
Rethrow as BuildFailedException: Exception of type 'UnityEditor.Build.BuildFailedException' was thrown.
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.CancelPostProcess.AbortBuild (System.String title, System.String message, System.Exception ex) (at :0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at :0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, AndroidPlayerBuildProgram.Data.AndroidPlayerBuildProgramOutput buildProgramOutput) (at :0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at :0)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.Int32 subtarget, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at <36f62d8e760b48f7af5d32916f997ce1>:0)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)`

If i delete the libraries than the build will successded but the applicaiton is not working perfectly.

Packages in build.

- AVPRO
- FirebaseCrashlytics
- FirebaseAnalytics
- FirebaseDynamicLinks

[Resovler Android Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3dYo.jpg)
[Publishing Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8BjV.jpg)

Trying to make Andoird Build in unity.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Solved! 
Need to enable Progaurd file bool from publishing setting of player setting and add these lines in mainTemplate.gradle 

    implementation 'com.google.guava:listenablefuture:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'